# Refactoring controllers - Form Validation Request with conditionals

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a submit method which is pretty big, and I need to scale it out. I'm going to put the validation logic into a request class.

How can I replicate my conditionals as an if statement.

For example this rule checks if the user has accepted the terms before submitting

1 is the no value

```
if(!($request->has('terms') && $request->terms == 1)){
            return redirect()->back()->withFlashDanger("Please accept terms and condition.");}
```

How would i write this in the rules method in my request class

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Accepted](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-accepted) validation rule:

```
'terms' => 'accepted',
```

> The field under validation must be yes, on, 1, or true. This is useful for validating "Terms of Service" acceptance.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function rules()
{

    return [
        'terms' => 'required|in:1',
    ];
}
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-in for more info

Comment: what does in:1 do?

Comment: that's the acceptable value, correspondig to $request->terms == 1